# Core dumped/ Segmentation fault when running the code

Tags: c

When I run this I get a warning regarding returning the local address, which is reasonable since all these functions will return a local address. However, I need the functions to return a matrix since I need modulation in my code. The major issue is that I get a core dumped/ segmentation fault error when running this on my PC.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<math.h>

    #define N 10

    float *A[N], *B[N], *C[N];
    int i, j, k;

    float** matrix_create(int n){
      float* M[n];
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        M[i] = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
      return M;
    }

    float** add(float* M1[], float* M2[], int n){
      float** M3 = matrix_create(n);
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
          M3[i][j] = M1[i][j] + M2[i][j];
      return M3;
    }

    float** sub(float* M1[], float* M2[], int n){
      float** M3 = matrix_create(n);
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
          M3[i][j] = M1[i][j] - M2[i][j];
      return M3;
    }

    void print(float* M[], int n){
      for (i = 0; i <  n; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
          printf("%f\t", M[i][j] );
        printf("\n");
        }
    }

    int main(){

      int count = 0, i,j, k;

      for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        A[i] = (float*)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
      for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        B[i] = (float*)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
      for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        C[i] = (float*)malloc(N * sizeof(float));


       for (i = 0; i <  N; i++)
         for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
            A[i][j] = ++count;
            B[i][j] = count;
            }

    float** D = add(A, B, N);
    print(D, N);


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heyo,

The segmentation fault happens as a result of what the compiler is warning you about! In the `matrix_create` function, you create a local array of `float*`. In c, when you return an array, it will only return the address of the first element in the array. When the function returns, the stack shrinks, and this memory is no longer part of your program. When you use the `[]` operator, you're dereferencing the pointer to the address that `matrix_create` returns. Since this memory doesn't belong to your program anymore, you get a segmentation fault. In order to solve it, you should also allocate the required memory for the `float*` on the heap with `malloc`, such that you can keep using the memory after the function returns:

```
float** matrix_create(int n){
    float** M = malloc(n * sizeof(float*));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    M[i] = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    return M;
}
```

Keep in mind that you shouldn't just allocate memory on the heap, you should also free it after you no longer need it!

Comment: Thank you so much the amazing explanation. what about the frist line when I allocate the memory statically?

Comment: what would be the free line of code be? in a loop?

Comment: When you use the `static` keyword, memory will be preallocated for it outside the heap or the stack! The memory location is always the same, so when you assign the variable once in a function call, and the function exits, you can use the exact same variable again the next time you call the function. One way to think about it would be that every call to the function would use the exact same variable. (Editing it once, edits it everywhere)!

Comment: When you use `x = malloc(N)`, you ask the OS to give you N amount of memory to use for your program. This memory is allocated on the heap, and therefore when your function exits, the memory persist. Unfortunately, memory is not infinite, so it is good practice to "give" the memory you allocate back to the OS by using a call to `free(x)`. I would recommend to do some reading on the differences between how memory is reserved when you declare/define a variable normally (on the stack), when you use malloc (on the heap), and when you use the `static` keyword!

Comment: Thank yo for your great explanations, however bay statically I meant the line of cod eI used in my program: float* M[n]. Why this doesn't work?

Comment: `float* M[n]` creates an array of float pointers of size n in the local stack frame of the `matrix_create` function. When they array returns, this stack frame is removed from the stack, and that means that the memory for the array does not belong to your program anymore. If you do try to access it, then you can get a segmentation fault! A segmentation fault occurs when you try to access memory that does not belong to your program.